Creating a Custom Autocomplete Script in ZSH Around Project Root Path
I'm trying to create a script that will mimic cd where I provide a path, and the script cd's to that by appending it to an absolute existing path. The idea is that wherever I call it, it will always act as if I'm trying to cd from the root of the project.
A key feature I want to add is autocomplete as the user is typing where, like cd, it will provide the path options and the user can autocomplete as they type.
Example:
goto po
pointers/    positions/

goto pointers/
src/         lib/

This is the initial script I made so far:
#!/bin/zsh

# Find the root directory of the repository
find_repo_root() {
    local repo_root
    repo_root=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel 2>/dev/null)
    if [ -z "$repo_root" ]; then
        return 1  # Return failure if not in a Git repository
    fi
    echo $repo_root
}

# Change directory relative to repository root
goto() {
    local repo_root=$(find_repo_root)
    if [ -z "$repo_root" ]; then
        echo "Error: Not in a Git repository." >&2  # Print error message to stderr
        return 1
    fi

    # Create an absolute path using the repo root
    local target_dir="$repo_root/$1"
    if [ -d "$target_dir" ]; then
        cd "$target_dir"
    else
        echo "Directory does not exist: $target_dir" >&2
        return 1
    fi
}

# Autocomplete function for the goto command
_goto_autocomplete() {
    local repo_root=$(find_repo_root)
    if [ -z "$repo_root" ]; then
        return 1  # If not in a Git repo, don't suggest any autocompletions
    fi

    # Dynamically generate possible matches relative to the repo root
    local current_input="${(Q)PREFIX}"

    # Find directories relative to the repository root, not the current directory
    local possible_dirs=(${(f)"$(find $repo_root -type d -not -path '*/\.*' -maxdepth 2)"})

    # Filter for directories that start with the current input
    local matches=()
    for dir in $possible_dirs; do
        # Strip the repository root from the beginning of the directory path
        local rel_dir=${dir#$repo_root/}
        if [[ $rel_dir == $current_input* ]]; then
            matches+=$rel_dir
        fi
    done

    # Provide autocomplete suggestions
    compadd $matches
}

# Register the autocomplete function for the goto command
compdef _goto_autocomplete goto

# Ensure compinit is loaded for autocompletion to work
autoload -Uz compinit && compinit

At first I thought I had it working since it starts to autocomplete, but then I realized it was always looking at the current working directory I was in. I'm not understanding how compadd, compdef, and compinit is working. I'm reading the docs for more insight, but I can't tell how to make the autocomplete only look at the provided filepath.

When writing completion functions for zsh, it's almost always better to use the existing utility functions instead of calling compadd directly. They provide a more consistent and customizable experience for users, with a lot less code. I recommend this reference guide for getting started with zsh completion, as the official documentation tends to be overly complex.
For this script, _files -/ -W "$repo_root" does exactly what you want: completing directories (-/) relative to $repo_root (-W).
_goto_autocomplete() {
    local repo_root
    if ! repo_root=$(find_repo_root); then
        _message 'not in a git repository'
        # Return 0 so no other completers are tried
        return 0
    fi

    # Using _arguments here instead of just _files so it doesn't try to
    # complete more than one argument
    _arguments ': :_files -/ -W "$repo_root"'
}

